# How to uncheck the last checked item in mat checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to uncheck the last checked item from mat checkbox, please find the below code...

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index;">
      <md-checkbox [checked]="item.checked" (change)="onChange($event, i, item)">
        {{item.label}}
 </md-checkbox>
```

```
data = [
    { label: 'one', checked: false },
    { label: 'two', checked: false },
    { label: 'three', checked: true },
    { label: 'four', checked: false },
    { label: 'five', checked: false }
    ];

onChange(event, index, item) {

      item.checked = !item.checked;

      this.lastAction = 'index: ' + index + ', label: ' + item.label + ', checked: ' + item.checked;

      console.log(index, event, item);

  }
```

Comment: What do you mean remove? Does it have to disappear? Or are you talking about only having one checkbox checked at a time?

Comment: I mean Uncheck the last checked item

Answer (score 1):

```
//First find last element of your array than remove like below on change event
data = [

    { label: 'one', checked: false },
    { label: 'two', checked: false },
    { label: 'three', checked: true },
    { label: 'four', checked: false },
    { label: 'five', checked: false }
    ];
var lastfind=data.slice(-1)[0];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
console.log(lastfind.label);
console.log(data.label);
if(data[i].label==lastfind.label){
console.log('test');
  data.splice(-1,1)
}
}
console.log(data);
```